# What is the relation between cargo smoke and EDTO?

Tags: safety, airline-operations, fire

I have heard a lot of people discussing about cargo smoke and Extended Diversion Time Operations (EDTO) together. Just want to know how these two affect each other.

Comment: Extended Diversion Time Operations https://www.icao.int/SAM/Documents/2014-EDTO/Draft%20EDTO%20Handbook%20edited%20only%20for%20training%20(2).pdf